# If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are ordinals. Then $\gamma=\alpha\cap\beta$ is an ordinal

Tags: proof-verification, ordinals

Does my attempt look fine or contain gaps? Thank you so much!

---

> **Theorem:** If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are ordinals. Then $\gamma=\alpha\cap\beta$ is an ordinal.

---

**Proof:**

- $\gamma$ is well-ordered

Since $\gamma\subseteq\alpha$ and $\alpha$ is well-ordered, $\gamma$ is well-ordered.

- $\gamma$ is transitive

If $\delta\in\theta\in\gamma$, then $\theta\in \alpha$ and $\theta\in \beta$. Then $\delta\in\theta\in \alpha$ and $\delta\in\theta\in \beta$. Then $\delta\in \alpha$ and $\delta\in \beta$ by the fact that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are transitive. Hence $\delta\in\alpha\cap\beta=\gamma$.

Comment: And what's the order on $\gamma$?

Comment: Hi @NajibIdrissi! All ordinals in the theorem are ordered under $\in$.

Comment: Your proof is correct. I would suggest rewriting the question to proving $\alpha\cap\beta$ is an ordinal and porting your proof to an answer and self-accepting it. See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3590).

Comment: Thank you so much for your guideline @SimplyBeautifulArt ;)